# Mi camara no se mueve, HelloCardboard (Unity)

Tags: unity, vr, realidad-aumentada

Soy nuevo en la programacion de VR en unity y para mi primer proyecto segui la guia rapida de google para usar el cardboard, pude implementar todo, soluciones varios errores y pude compilar mi app y correrla en mi dispositio correctamente. Pero el problema principal es que no puedo mover la camara con el giroscopio de mi celular ni mucho menos con los dedos, y tambien no se ve la vista doble que tienen para los cardboard como vi que tienen muchos tutoriales que siguen esta guia.
No creo que sea problema de mi dispositivo pq en la ventana de juego en Unity cuando lo corro tampoco puedo moverme (En los tutoriales vi que lo hacen con Alt + Click).

Este es el link de la Guia: https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart?hl=es-419

En mi camara hay un script que dice `Missing` pero no se si es ese el error.

> The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing!

Esta es la vista que tiene mi celular, no puedo mover la camara ni tampoco se ve doble

[image: Esta es la vista que tiene mi celular, no puedo mover la camara ni tampoco se ve doble]

Creo que encontre el error:

```
Initializing XR Failed.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
VrModeController/<StartXR>d__10:MoveNext () (at Assets/Samples/Google Cardboard XR Plugin for Unity/1.21.0/Hello Cardboard/Scripts/VrModeController.cs:148)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)
```